# toggle of jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle, fade, slide

I am making a div slide function.
I want a div fade and toggle in designated orientation

such as I click right btn,the div will fade from left to right
and I click left btn,the div will fade from right to left

this is my half finished code,div's position shouldn't change,
just make it disappeared like slide
http://jsfiddle.net/pL5g2/4/

my code can't achieve my purpose because I can't control the toggle direction.
dose anyone have a good idea?

Comment: So maybe add another parameter to specify the direction? @anonymousdownvotingislame - You have a great name, too. I completely agree.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your idea. I modified the code like the below

```
$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(offset, speed, easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({
        opacity: 'toggle',
        width: 'toggle',
        left: offset
    }, speed, easing, callback);
};

// sample to use the above function.
$("#right").click(function() {
    $(".block").slideFadeToggle("+=50px", "slow");
});

$("#left").click(function() {
    $(".block").slideFadeToggle("-=50px", "slow");
});​
```

I created a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/guanxiaohua2k6/gDz74/). Please confirm with it.